# creating a new column based on dynamically changing threshold conditions Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create a shiny app where the user selects a variable from a drop down box, e.g. dose or supp in the toothgrowth dataset, then a slider from 1 to 100 for each unique element in the variable is available, e.g  0.5, 1, 2 if dose is selected. Based on the variable selected and selected values on the slider I want to create another binary variable, e.g. sufficient_length, that is:

```
    if (input$group == "supp"){
      ToothGrowth$sufficient_length[which(ToothGrowth$supp=="VC" & ToothGrowth$len > input$VC)]<-1
      ToothGrowth$sufficient_length[which(ToothGrowth$supp=="VC" & ToothGrowth$len <= input$VC)]<-0
      ToothGrowth$sufficient_length[which(ToothGrowth$supp=="OJ" & ToothGrowth$len > input$OJ)]<-1
      ToothGrowth$sufficient_length[which(ToothGrowth$supp=="OJ" & ToothGrowth$len <= input$OJ)]<-0
    } else if (input$group == "dose"){
      ToothGrowth$sufficient_length[which(ToothGrowth$dose=="0.5" & ToothGrowth$len > input$"0.5")]<-1
      ToothGrowth$sufficient_length[which(ToothGrowth$dose=="0.5" & ToothGrowth$len <= input$"0.5")]<-0
      ToothGrowth$sufficient_length[which(ToothGrowth$dose=="1" & ToothGrowth$len > input$"1")]<-1
      ToothGrowth$sufficient_length[which(ToothGrowth$dose=="1" & ToothGrowth$len <= input$"1")]<-0
      ToothGrowth$sufficient_length[which(ToothGrowth$dose=="2" & ToothGrowth$len > input$"2")]<-1
      ToothGrowth$sufficient_length[which(ToothGrowth$dose=="2" & ToothGrowth$len <= input$"2")]<-0
    }
```

Is there a way of doing this without having to hard code all the possibilities as once I get this working I will apply it to a much larger dataset than `toothgroup` where there are many variables and more unique elements within those variables?

The full code for the shinny app so far is:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
data("ToothGrowth")

ui<-shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 4, 
             selectInput("group", "Group:", 
                         c("Supp" = "supp",
                           "Dose" = "dose")),
             uiOutput("sliders"),
             tableOutput("summary")
      ),
      mainPanel(

        # Output: Histogram ----
        plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")

      )
    )
  )
)

server <- shinyServer( function(input, output) { 

  dat<-reactive({
    as.character(unique(ToothGrowth[,input$group]))
  })

  #reactive code for referrals based on the slider for threshold----
  dat2 <- reactive({
    req(ToothGrowth)
    ToothGrowth$sufficient_length<-rep(0,nrow(ToothGrowth))
    if (input$group == "supp"){
      ToothGrowth$sufficient_length[which(ToothGrowth$supp=="VC" & ToothGrowth$len > input$VC)]<-1
      ToothGrowth$sufficient_length[which(ToothGrowth$supp=="VC" & ToothGrowth$len <= input$VC)]<-0
      ToothGrowth$sufficient_length[which(ToothGrowth$supp=="OJ" & ToothGrowth$len > input$OJ)]<-1
      ToothGrowth$sufficient_length[which(ToothGrowth$supp=="OJ" & ToothGrowth$len <= input$OJ)]<-0
    } else if (input$group == "dose"){
      ToothGrowth$sufficient_length[which(ToothGrowth$dose=="0.5" & ToothGrowth$len > input$"0.5")]<-1
      ToothGrowth$sufficient_length[which(ToothGrowth$dose=="0.5" & ToothGrowth$len <= input$"0.5")]<-0
      ToothGrowth$sufficient_length[which(ToothGrowth$dose=="1" & ToothGrowth$len > input$"1")]<-1
      ToothGrowth$sufficient_length[which(ToothGrowth$dose=="1" & ToothGrowth$len <= input$"1")]<-0
      ToothGrowth$sufficient_length[which(ToothGrowth$dose=="2" & ToothGrowth$len > input$"2")]<-1
      ToothGrowth$sufficient_length[which(ToothGrowth$dose=="2" & ToothGrowth$len <= input$"2")]<-0
    }
    return(ToothGrowth)
  })


  #Render the sliders
  output$sliders <- renderUI({
    # First, create a list of sliders each with a different name
    sliders <- lapply(1:length(dat()), function(i) {
      inputName <- dat()[i]
      sliderInput(inputName, inputName, min=0, max=100, value=10)
    })
    # Create a tagList of sliders (this is important)
    do.call(tagList, sliders)
  })

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(dat2(),aes(len,fill = as.factor(sufficient_length)))+
      geom_histogram(bins=20)

  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Sure, this example can compactify a little down to `+((dose_selected && ((dose == 1 && len > 1_dose_slider_value) || (dose == 2 && len > 2_dose_slider_value))) || (supp_selected && ((supp == OJ && len > OJ_supp_slider_value) || (supp == VC && len > VC_supp_slider_value))))` (apologies for the dump), but I don't know if that helps much. It's a little difficult to know for certain without a little more context (it would be nice to have real code). Further, expanding to a larger dataset is vague, do mean many more rows, or different columns/categoricals?

Comment: BTW: using `&` suggests that you are working on a vector of values, not singletons. One consequence of using `&` is that it will not use short-circuit logic. If you really do have a vector of values, then a fuller examples is further justified. If not, then, perhaps it would be informative to know the difference between [`&` and `&&`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Logic.html).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the code for the shiny app to date - I have now included it. The thing I would like to avoid is explicitly coding `dose` and `dose==1` etc and rather try make this coding more general to what ever drop down option is selected, e.g. `dose`, `supp`,... In the larger dataset there will be different and more columns and more categories per column.

Comment: (1) What are you intending to do with `sufficient_length`? In this context, it seems like it should be `nrow(ToothGrowth)` long (so your use of `&` is correct). (2) You say *"if dose == 1"*, but there is no way for the user to choose which to do. (3) Ultimately, can you include what `sufficient_length` should look like given one particular set of user-selections?

Comment: I've now added more detailed code and an example of how I would use `sufficient_length` in a ggplot. The main thing is to find out if there is a nice way of calculating `sufficient_length` for all the combinations without hard coding with else if statements like I have above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this trick, which (I think) is robust to the number of levels.

```r
  dat2 <- reactive({
    req(input$group)

    ToothGrowth$sufficient_length <- 
      +apply(
        outer(ToothGrowth$len, mapply(`[[`, list(input), dat()), FUN=`>`) &
          outer(ToothGrowth[[input$group]], dat(), `==`),
        1, any)

    return(ToothGrowth)
  })
```

Walk-through, assuming that `dose` is selected, and the sliders are set to 30, 20, and 10 for "0.5", "1" and "2", respectively.

1. Equivalent to the verbatim `ToothGrowth$dose`, this instead grabs the levels from the selected `group` programmatically.

   ```r
   ToothGrowth[[input$group]]
   #  [1] 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
   # [20] 1.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5
   # [39] 0.5 0.5 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0
   # [58] 2.0 2.0 2.0
   ```
2. We want to see if `$len` is greater than *all of the sliders' values*, so the `outer` command gives us a matrix of `nrow(ToothGrowth)` rows and 3 columns (3 because `dat()` has three elements, the three levels of `$dose`). Column 1 represents the first slider (`"0.5"` when `dose` selected), column 2 represents the second slider (`"1"`), and column 3 represents the third slider (`"2"`).

   ```r
   ToothGrowth$len
   #  [1]  4.2 11.5  7.3  5.8  6.4 10.0 11.2 11.2  5.2  7.0 16.5 16.5 15.2 17.3 22.5
   # [16] 17.3 13.6 14.5 18.8 15.5 23.6 18.5 33.9 25.5 26.4 32.5 26.7 21.5 23.3 29.5
   # [31] 15.2 21.5 17.6  9.7 14.5 10.0  8.2  9.4 16.5  9.7 19.7 23.3 23.6 26.4 20.0
   # [46] 25.2 25.8 21.2 14.5 27.3 25.5 26.4 22.4 24.5 24.8 30.9 26.4 27.3 29.4 23.0
   mapply(`[[`, list(input), dat())
   # [1] 30 18 10
   head(outer(ToothGrowth$len, mapply(`[[`, list(input), dat()), FUN=`>`))
   #       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
   # [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
   # [2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
   # [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
   # [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
   # [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
   # [6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
   ```

   The one `TRUE` there means that the second value of `$len` (11.5) is greater than the third slider value (which is 10, per my setup).
3. The `mapply` is a trick to get the values of multiple `input$` elements. Normally, if we have a named `list`, we can use single `[` for indexing multiple values, but that doesn't work with the special `input$` object. While I'd like to use `sapply(dat(),`[[`, x = input)`, but that doesn't work (not implemented within the `shiny` stuff, not a surprise as who would want/need to access it like that). So I use `mapply` to work around that.

   ```r
   mapply(`[[`, list(input), dat())
   # [1] 30 20 10
   ```
4. Now that we have a matrix of 60x3 (from bullet 2), we need a similar matrix that indicates whether that row's `$dose` is equal to the column's levels. In the previous bullet, the `TRUE` indicates a value of 11.5 (row 2) and a `$dose` of `"2"` (column 3, slider 3). So now we do an `outer` comparison of `$dose` with the available levels.

   ```r
   dat()
   # [1] "0.5" "1"   "2"  
   head(outer(ToothGrowth[[input$group]], dat(), `==`))
   #      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
   # [1,] TRUE FALSE FALSE
   # [2,] TRUE FALSE FALSE
   # [3,] TRUE FALSE FALSE
   # [4,] TRUE FALSE FALSE
   # [5,] TRUE FALSE FALSE
   # [6,] TRUE FALSE FALSE
   ```
5. From here, we take the two 60x3 matrices and do an element-wise AND:

   ```r
   head(outer(ToothGrowth[[input$group]], dat(), `==`) &
         outer(ToothGrowth$len, mapply(`[[`, list(input), dat()), FUN=`>`))
   #       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
   # [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
   # [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
   # [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
   # [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
   # [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
   # [6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
   tail(outer(ToothGrowth[[input$group]], dat(), `==`) &
         outer(ToothGrowth$len, mapply(`[[`, list(input), dat()), FUN=`>`))
   #        [,1]  [,2] [,3]
   # [55,] FALSE FALSE TRUE
   # [56,] FALSE FALSE TRUE
   # [57,] FALSE FALSE TRUE
   # [58,] FALSE FALSE TRUE
   # [59,] FALSE FALSE TRUE
   # [60,] FALSE FALSE TRUE
   ```

   (Okay, not much interesting there, just thought I'd show both head and tail to demonstrate that some rows have a match.)
6. `apply` takes a matrix (the element-wise AND of the two matrices, and applies a function (`any`) to each row (`1`, the margin on which the function is applied).

Verification that the values are the same:

```r
## my code, assigned elsewhere for now
ind <- +apply(
  outer(ToothGrowth$len, mapply(`[[`, list(input), dat()), FUN=`>`) &
    outer(ToothGrowth[[input$group]], dat(), `==`),
  1, any)
## your code
ToothGrowth$sufficient_length[which(ToothGrowth$dose=="0.5" & ToothGrowth$len > input$"0.5")]<-1
ToothGrowth$sufficient_length[which(ToothGrowth$dose=="0.5" & ToothGrowth$len <= input$"0.5")]<-0
ToothGrowth$sufficient_length[which(ToothGrowth$dose=="1" & ToothGrowth$len > input$"1")]<-1
ToothGrowth$sufficient_length[which(ToothGrowth$dose=="1" & ToothGrowth$len <= input$"1")]<-0
ToothGrowth$sufficient_length[which(ToothGrowth$dose=="2" & ToothGrowth$len > input$"2")]<-1
ToothGrowth$sufficient_length[which(ToothGrowth$dose=="2" & ToothGrowth$len <= input$"2")]<-0

all(ind == ToothGrowth$sufficient_length)
# [1] TRUE
```

(BTW: `req(ToothGrowth)` in this example is completely unnecessary, as `ToothGrowth` is a static data set. Typically, `req` is used on reactive values to ensure that it is "truthy" in its current reactive state. This happens frequently-enough, such as on startup when some inputs are not-yet defined completely and therefore might return as `NULL`. So you should really be using `req` on `input$...` or some reactive data in your server component.)

Comment: Thank you - that is such a tidy solution!